# Slow while loop over regex.exec in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, while-loop

I'm trying to parse a 14Mb file containing ~330k STEP-rows that looks something like this:
`#328489=IFCCOMPOSITECURVESEGMENT(.CONTINUOUS.,.F.,#328487);`

```
let regex = /#(\d+)\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*\(([\s\S]*?)\);/g;
let match;
let res1;
let res2;
let res3;

while(match !== null) {
  match = regex.exec(data);

  res1 = match[1];
  res2 = match[2];
  res3 = match[3];
}
```

My problem is that this is EXTREMELY slow! It takes forever to parse the file (maybe 200 rows per second). And this is a small file! They can be more than 100Mb and contain millions of rows.

Why is this so slow? If I stringify the indata and use match instead: `let result = data.toString().match(regex);` it only takes a few milliseconds. But I really would prefer to be able to keep the grouping that I get when I use exec.

Comment: Is `data` one line of the input or the entire input? What is the type of `data`? If you're processing just one line at a time, there are a number of optimizations you can make to your expression, such as starting it with `^` and ending it with `$`, and removing the `g` modifier from the expression.

Comment: I'm using fileStream in Node at the moment and I get a big blob of all the data. It will probably be a string in the end and at the moment it's reading the entire file.

Comment: The problem is that STEP-lines can have line breaks. So it's not ideal to read the file line by line

Comment: Just a reminder: you can unroll lazy dot patterns. This will work faster: `/#(\d+)\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*\(([^)]*(?:\)(?!;)[^)]*)*)\);/g`

Comment: Thanks. But not much of a difference in this case

Comment: What do you mean by _stringify the indata_?  Is the indata not a string already?